# Game Development using Unity3d

Tags: c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-development

[Pako Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns9Nx.jpg)

Hi there, I am just starting game development. Specifically with Unity, Android Studio, and  C#. Me and my group planned to make a game for our thesis. The problem is that, our professors want us to make a 3D game if possible. Our proposed game is something like Dr.Driving a car simulation where it involves safety signs, road signs and their regulation. Wherein it should look like in the picture(the pako game) 
 
And my question is that, is it easy to make a 3D game for someone newbie like me? Is there any way where I can just import package assets or API? so that I won't spend much more time in designing the environments and even the car? 
Your reply will be appreciated. Thank you very much :)
credits to the picture: Pako Game

Answer (score 1):

1. Spent some time learning the interface, Unity3D is a game engine and as any other game engine, is just a toolbox that let you do things in multiple ways: https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/interface-overview
2. Forget about your project and spent some time discovering Unity SDK, make a simple pong or tetris or space invader just to get a habit of how Unity forces you to do things it's way (quite different than common OOP)
3. Discover the [Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/) to find packages that could help you, at least for the visual and the 3C of a game (Character, Camera, Control)

Then and until then, you can be able to sit down and implement your custom game logic. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir Omar Guendeli. Yes, I will do it, until  I'll be able to familiar the whole unity. :)

Answer (score 0):

> is it easy to make a 3D game for someone newbie like me?

There are a lot of flavors of newbie. You will need to:

1. Have or gain some mastery over the Unity interface.
2. Have or gain some mastery over programming (I'd say in C#).
3. Have or gain some mastery over Blender* (or rely on 3rd party assets)
4. Have or gain some mastery over Audacity* (or rely on 3rd party assets)
5. Have or gain some mastery over story-telling, project management, etc...

So perhaps the *easy* answer is, "No."? Ultimately, what is easy for one is not easy for another. Easy or not, there *will* be a lot of *work* involved, if you plan to create anything worthwhile.  That's how it "works".

> Is there any way where I can just import package assets or API? so that I won't spend much more time in designing the environments and even the car?

As mentioned, the Asset Store can help you get quickly from A to B or even X, Y or Z. There are assets that are basically complete mini-games, ready to be branded and rolled-out, and there are assets that are just a model or pack of sound-effects. And of course, everything in-between.

In your case, it sounds like you might also need to have or gain some mastery with a modeling tool, such as Blender.  It might be your easiest way to get the specific assets you need in terms of the safety signs, but then again, if you are using generic stop and yield type signs the chances are the assets can be found in either the Asset Store, or a 3rd party site like a Blender model site.

*Note: I mention Audacity and Blender because they are free to use, but of course you can use whatever software you like to create your audio and graphical assets.

For those who find the learning curve of Unity too steep for their time or their project, perhaps something like [Game Builder](https://store.steampowered.com/app/929860/Game_Builder/) would be a better starting-point.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much for your help Sir Jack Draak :)